# React - how to make an summary view for the table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i download all my data into json.
I have data like

```
[
  {
    orderId: 1,
    orderedItems: [
      {
        itemId: 1,
        itemValue: 33.33
      },
      {
        itemId: 2,
        itemValue: 55.33
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    orderId: 2,
    orderedItems: [
      {
        itemId: 1,
        itemValue: 33.33
      },
      {
        itemId: 2,
        itemValue: 55.33
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And with this data im doing the reduce, it look like:

```
item.productId
    .map(prod => {
      const product = item.magazyn.find(p => p.productId === prod.productId);
      if (product) {
        return (
          Math.round(
            (prod.productQuantity *
              (product.productNettoSellingPrice +
                product.productNettoSellingPrice * (product.productVatRate / 100)) -
              prod.productQuantity *
                (product.productNettoSellingPrice +
                  product.productNettoSellingPrice * (product.productVatRate / 100)) *
                (row.original.contractorIndividualDiscount / 100) -
              prod.productQuantity *
                (product.productNettoSellingPrice +
                  product.productNettoSellingPrice * (product.productVatRate / 100)) *
                (product.productDiscount / 100)) *
              100
          ) / 100
        );
      }
      return 0;
    })
    .reduce((total, currentValue) => total + currentValue, 0);
```

And it starting to look like this:
[image: no description here]

But the point is how to summary all data which was reduced before? I trying to make .reduce for this .reduce but gives me null or [Object object] :P
This table is only the most easiest table in html, with table tr td...
Can someone help to summary all of those values?

I know how to summary all values of items of one order but i cannot summary all values of all orders.

Comment: Please format your code with Prettier or another formatter so it is easier to read.

Comment: Please include a legible example of what you actually want. It's not clear what the specific issue is. A display of `[Object object]` means you're displaying the default string representation of an object--so far it seems like some logging or breakpoints would be enough to resolve the issue.

Comment: I want to summary the order incomes.
I have a function to write those incomes, but i dont have once to merge all incomes. Thats it

Comment: @ionosphere the json is just an example, you dont have to look at this. 
I mean the function with reduce gives me 3 variables each for one order, but for now i want to summary them, merge into one value to know summary of the all orders

Comment: Can you create a ReactJS fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx)?

Comment: @LajosArpad Not really i just make an while to create rows with prices. For now i want to do this and also summary it, but i dont know how :P Im trying some methods and im just too stupid to understand what did i wrote :D

Comment: That's a solvable problem. There are online available Javascript/ReactJS fiddles (a fiddle is a web place where you can create a small program where you illustrate a solution or a problem) where you could implement your problem in a minimal, reproducible manner, so we, fellow developers will be able to play around with it instead of guessing the part of the code that you do not show. You are using quite a few structures in your code that you did not define in your question, hence I have trouble implementing a test project for you. I was asking you and ask again to provide a minimal...

Comment: ...reproducible example so I can solve your problem.

Comment: Your question should include a [mre]. Please see [ask].

Comment: @3milBow There's no way to help you without a minimal reproducible example here. Your code has nothing visibly wrong with it, and since we don't know what any of the variables/properties have in them or how you're using the values later, there's no way to investigate any further.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize all the reduced values from multiple orders, you can use an additional `reduce` operation:

```js
const orders = [
  {
    orderId: 1,
    orderedItems: [
      {
        itemId: 1,
        itemValue: 33.33
      },
      {
        itemId: 2,
        itemValue: 55.33
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    orderId: 2,
    orderedItems: [
      {
        itemId: 1,
        itemValue: 33.33
      },
      {
        itemId: 2,
        itemValue: 55.33
      }
    ]
  }
];

const totalValue = orders.reduce((acc, order) => {
  const orderValue = order.orderedItems.reduce((orderAcc, item) => {
    return orderAcc + item.itemValue;
  }, 0);
  return acc + orderValue;
}, 0);

console.log("Total value:", totalValue); // Total value: 177.32
```

The outer `reduce` iterates over each order in the `orders` array. Inside the outer `reduce`, the inner `reduce` operation sums up the `itemValue` of each item in the `orderedItems` array for each order. The result is accumulated in the `orderValue` variable.

Finally, the outer `reduce` returns the accumulated total value (`acc`) plus the `orderValue` for each order. The initial value for the outer `reduce` is set to `0`, indicating that the total value starts at `0`.

Comment: You're not wrong here, but the OP's code is clearly not operating directly off of that `orders` list, so I don't think this answer is too relevant. Even if it was relevant though, you'd certainly want to `map` over each order and `reduce` them there so that you can display each order's total (as seen in the screenshot) and then `reduce` that list to get the total.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, check if the `.map` call is returning an array of numbers (if any variable used inside is an object and not a number, then the result of the arithmetic expression will be `NaN`).

If it is actually an array of numbers, then you can declare a variable and iterate over the returned array with `.forEach`, adding the price to the variable on each iteration (hardcoded reduction):

```
var total = 0;
item.productId
.map(prod => {
  const product = item.magazyn.find(p => p.productId === prod.productId);
  if (product) {
    return (
      Math.round(
        (prod.productQuantity *
          (product.productNettoSellingPrice +
            product.productNettoSellingPrice * (product.productVatRate / 100)) -
          prod.productQuantity *
            (product.productNettoSellingPrice +
              product.productNettoSellingPrice * (product.productVatRate / 100)) *
            (row.original.contractorIndividualDiscount / 100) -
          prod.productQuantity *
            (product.productNettoSellingPrice +
              product.productNettoSellingPrice * (product.productVatRate / 100)) *
            (product.productDiscount / 100)) *
          100
      ) / 100
    );
  }
  return 0;
})
.forEach(val=>total+=val);
```

Comment: The code you provided here is functionally the same as the OP's code. This should have been a comment.

Comment: I don't have reputation enough for comment.